# How to test phonenumber_field.modelfields.PhoneNumberField

Tags: django, django-models, django-testing

I am using [django-phonenumber-field](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field) to store a phone number in my model. While covering the model with unit tests, raised a question of what would be an appropriate unit tests to test this field.

The module itself is well tested and I should not retest this logic. But what shall I test instead?

```
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
class User(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
  phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False,
      unique=True, help_text='Phone number')
```

Answer (score 1):

No, You should not write the unit tests for the packages you install using `pip`.

If you want to still test the `PhoneNumberField` then make a set of the valid and invalid phone numbers and test with it.

- Valid Numbers for PhoneNumberField:

```
 +91 1234567890
 +917456987451
 +91-5689741236
```

- Invalid Numbers for PhoneNumberField:

```
 7894561230
 +6985471230
 +9-56457895412
```